# How can I set [output_adapter.email] with Aruba address in wso2 Identity Server v. 5.11.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, email-notifications, smtps, email-publisher

I'm trying to  set an email sender (for example recovery password). I already set with a Gmail and Outlook address mail and it's work!
Now i nedd to configure an Aruba hostmail.
this is my deployment.toml configuration module

```
[output_adapter.email]
from_address= "****@aruba.it"
username= "*****@****.it"
password= "******"
hostname= "smtps.aruba.it"
port= 465
enable_start_tls= true
enable_authentication= true
signature = "****"

[output_adapter.email.custom_properties]
"mail.smtp.ssl.protocols"="TLSv1.2"
"mail.transport.protocol"="smtps"
```

Logs return

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter} - Event dropped at Output Adapter 'EmailPublisher' for tenant id '-1234', Error in message format, Could not connect to SMTP host: smtps.aruba.it, port: 465, response: -1 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtps.aruba.it, port: 465, response: -1
```

I tried with smpts and smpt (it should be the same port 465).
Can you tell me if it's not supported or something?
THanks, i really need help :(

Comment: Are you share that port is 465 and not 25? / according to https://serversmtp.com/smtp-aruba the port can be 465 / 25

Comment: Try `telnet smtps.aruba.it 465` / `telnet smtp.aruba.it 465`/ `telnet smtps.aruba.it 25`/ `telnet smtp.aruba.it 25`  in your command line to test whether the host is reachable or not?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I already tried with port 25, moreover trying with 'telnet' i got respons only with 465 port (both smtp/smtps). The issue remains open for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding these properties in deployment.toml file below this modules:

```
[output_adapter.email]
from_address= "***@aruba.it"
username= "****"
password= "****!"
hostname= "smtps.aruba.it"
port= 465
enable_start_tls= true
enable_authentication= true
signature = "WSO2"

[output_adapter.email.custom_properties]
"mail.smtp.ssl.protocols"="TLSv1.2"
"mail.smtp.debug"="true"
"mail.smtp.socketFactory.port"="465"
"mail.smtp.socketFactory.class"="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
"mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback"="false"
```